# Do I have to expose the port if I am using the ports config?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Do I have to expose the port if I am using the `ports` config?

In the `docker-compose.yml` below, do I have to keep `expose 2022` or can I remove it? Is there a difference between them?

```
  myproject-app:
    build: ../myproject-app
    container_name: myproject-app
    image: myproject-app
    expose:
      - 2022
    ports:
      - 2022:2022
    volumes:
      - ../myproject-app/:/home/myproject/myproject-app/
      - /home/myproject/myproject-app/node_modules
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exposed ports needed for another service, if you want to connect two services inside docker, so service with exposed port will be available inside docker net.

Ports property (`ports:`) make service port available on your host machine, so you can connect it with your OS net.

So you can delete expose property.

Answer (score 2):

"Expose" means basically nothing in modern Docker.  There is pretty much no reason to put an `expose:` line in your `docker-compose.yml` file.  It's considered polite to include an `EXPOSE` line in your Dockerfile to document what port(s) your service will listen on, but it's not strictly necessary.

In modern Docker, with named networks, any container can connect to any port of any other container on the same network, provided a process is listening there.  Before there were named networks, one container had to explicitly "link" to another to be able to call it, and then it could only reach the exposed ports of the target container.  This setup is considered obsolete now (you never need `links:` either).

Plain Docker has an option (`docker run -P`, with a capital `P`) to publish all exposed ports on random host ports.  Compose doesn't have an equivalent option.  Ports that are exposed but not published also show up in the `docker ps` output.  But those are really the only things "expose" does at all.